# How can I pause all the Audios when I play an audio in React / Next.js

Tags: reactjs, audio, next.js

This is my first time posting on StackOverflow.
I have been working on my personal project with Next.js.

Right now, when I click an audio button it plays, and if I play other buttons then they play as well. What I want to achieve is to stop all the other audio when I click an audio button so only one audio plays at a time.

Could anyone help me with it?

Here is my code :
(I just made it as simple as possible for this)

```
import Wrapper from "../../styles/test/testStyle";
import Audio from "../../components/Test/Test";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Audio audioSrc="/audio/0.mp3" />

      <Audio audioSrc="/audio/1.mp3" />

      <Audio audioSrc="/audio/2.mp3" />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Components :

```
import Wrapper from "./TestStyle";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Test = ({ audioSrc }) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audioRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current.play();
    } else {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    }

    audioRef.current.onended = () => {
      setIsPlaying(false);
    };
  });

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <audio src={audioSrc} ref={audioRef} />
      <button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>
        {isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}
      </button>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a state (store the music - or src - and isPlaying prop for each audio) and a handleClick function in the parent component:

```
  const [audioList, setAudioList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!audioList.length) {
      const newAudioList = [];
      audios.forEach((audio) => {
        newAudioList.push({
          music: audio,
          isPlaying: false
        });
      });
      setAudioList(newAudioList);
    }
  }, [audioList]);

  const handleAudio = (music) => {
    setAudioList((currentAudioList) => {
      const newAudioList = [...currentAudioList];
      newAudioList.forEach((audio) => {
        audio.isPlaying = music === audio.music && !audio.isPlaying;
      });
      return newAudioList;
    });
  };
```

Create the Audio element(s) with map, pass the music, isPlaying and handleAudio (and the setAudioList, if you want to change the isPlaying to false after the end of the music) as props. The ref can stay inside the Audio.